# Queueing or not queueing for low latency

Tags: c++, sockets, low-latency

I'm writing a low-latency program in C++ which receives data from a source, processes the data and sends to a target via a TCP socket. I have a separate thread for all these 3 modules, receiver thread, processor thread, sender thread. All these threads are communicating with lock-free queues.
Do you think that sending the message directly and not using the queue for the sender part would give lower latency? Does it affect performance stability?
Thanks

Comment: I think it's impossible to give a generic yes or no answer for all circumstances. This depends on so many things that just measuring is the only thing that really gives you a good answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the three threads? Wouldn't it be faster to just have a single thread receive the data, process it, and then send the reply without having to waste time switching threads? How does more threads give lower latency?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if the application can't afford to drop data, you need such design (separate receiver and processor threads with an event buffer in-between) to handle volume spikes. With the threads CPU pin'ed and using lock free data structure, no time is wasted switching threads. There is a slight cost of synchronizing CPU cache though. @ xyzt it's common to have processor thread to send data. Theoretically, the sender thread just writes data into socket buffer, right? (having said that, I've never benchmarked this. Please feel free to benchmark it to prove the theory)

Comment: @SPD I would think single threaded asynchronous is gonna work the same. And if it can't process packets fast enough, it has a different sort of problem and will run out of  memory eventually anyways. So I guess it's a matter kernel's RX queue size, load testing, benchmarking, and importantly profiling. @ xyzt no hand-waving argument is gonna help out here. You do have to do all three to get a definitive answer: benchmark and load test while profiling.

Comment: @TomTrebicky depends on the resiliency requirement/characteristics of packet flow, an app-level message queue is a way to handle network packet volume spike. If the processing speed is constantly slower than packet arrival speed, that's a totally different story.

Answer (score 0):

If the three threads are pinned to different physical cores, having a separate sender thread would give lower latency than processor thread doing the send operation, specially if there are retries happening in the send process. Even if it is a best effort async send, you could still save the marginal time it takes to write to the socket.